# Troubles using a Low-Dropout Linear Regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator, ldo

I've designed a board, that includes a charging part :

[image]

the problem that I have is in the LMS8117A-3.3:
[image]

here I can measure 5V on Pin1, but nothing on pin2, I was expecting 3.3V :
I've check the board and no I don't have any bypass, to test the board, I've put a 3.3V voltage at "target voltage pin" and the board works fine! So my question is how may solve this and what am I missing! 
This the layout part!

[image]

and here a link to the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lms8117a.pdf)

Comment: You appear to have the input and output pins on the LMS8117 swapped. Unless the part as shown is on the bottom of the board.

Comment: Yes, you have possibly connected the 5 V to the GND pin and GND to the input pin.

Comment: @JRE I suppose you should post it as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have swapped the ground and input pins.

[image]